# How to use FastClick.js with Phonegap and JQM?

Tags: jquery, performance, cordova, delay, fastclick.js

I've tried a few different ways to remove the 300ms delay due to the webkit browsers handling of touch events.  The library, FastClick.js, seems to be the preferred method, yet I'm having a little trouble implementing it. I've included it and also added an event listener, but I don't know if I've added the listener correctly.  Should this be working or am I failing to do something?
Thank you!

Consider the code below, where

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Calculator
    </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-   scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js">
    </script>
    <<script type='application/javascript' src='js/fastclick.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function onBodyLoad()
    {       
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
         $(function() {
         FastClick.attach(document.body);
         });

    }

    function onDeviceReady()
    {


    }
    </script>
    <script>
                window.addEventListener('load', function() {
                new FastClick(document.body);
                }, false);
    </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/jquerymobile.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/jquerymobile.nativedroid.css" type="text/css">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">   
</head>

<body onload="onBodyLoad()">
    <!--START OF PAGE 1-->
    <div data-role="page" data-theme='b' id="one">
        <div data-role="content">
              <a href="#one" data-transition="none" data-
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Another good one (which i use on my projects) is [Hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/)





.

Comment: I definitely recommend Hammer.js to anyone who is using Phonegap.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try with the below code.

```
function onBodyLoad()
{       
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

}

function onDeviceReady()
{
  alert('test');
  FastClick.attach(document.body);
}
```

If everything is fine, you should be able to see the alert box.

Have a look on http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/fast-touch-event-handling-eliminate-click-delay.html

Comment: Thank you,! I'll try both of your solutions and report back.  I can think of a few questions already, but I'll see if I can find the answers first. One more question, suppose FastClick is included and instatiated correctly, do I need to add any classes or code to my buttons, anchors, or links or is this already handled in the background?

Comment: I believe nothing else is required. The above link explains well.

Answer (score 0):

I can also think of another solution.. Note: I have not personally tried this..

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '.ui-page', function (event, data)
{
   FastClick.attach(activePage);
});
```

Comment: Would you add this to function onDeviceReady() just as you did FastClick.attach(document.body);?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can have that separately inside jquery document ready.. That should work..

Answer (score 0):

You should use the built in [`vclick` event](http://api.jquerymobile.com/vclick/) in jQuery Mobile - same idea as FastClick.

```
$(document).on('vclick', '#someButton', function(){ 

});
```

Source: [How to use FastClick with jQuery Mobile the right way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24239455/how-to-use-fastclick-with-jquery-mobile-the-right-way)