# Error nova framework nova.touch.bindClick

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I'm doing an application using phonegap and nova framework. I have problems when i call a page from another page.
I have three pages:
From the home page, touch in a button and go to the Page 1. In the Page 1 I have a header with two buttons (back and configuration). The back button goes to Home page and the configuration button goes to Page 2. In page two i have a headar (in the same position than page 1) and a button to close and return to page 1.
When I touch the close button the page 2 should go to Page 1 but however goes to page 2 but very fast, the page 1 is closed and returns to Home.

The events are different and are in different pages. The names buttons are different.

But not always does this, sometimes (depends on how it touches) works well.

I don't know how to fix and I need help.

Event from Page 1:

```
nova.touch.bindClick("#btnBack", function() {

        var page = new nova.Page("pages/home.html");
        page.needAddingToHistory = true;
        atApp.gotoPage(page);
    });

nova.touch.bindClick("#btnConf", function() {

        var page = new nova.Page("pages/page2.html");
        page.needAddingToHistory = true;
        atApp.gotoPage(page);
    });
```

Button Page 1:

```
<div id="btnBack" class="btn-left btn-cancel">
        <span><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>Back</span>
    </div>
<div id="btnConf" class="btn-right">
        <span><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></span>
    </div>
```

Event Page 2

```
nova.touch.bindClick("#btnClose", function() {       
        var page = new nova.Page("pages/page1.html");
         page.needAddingToHistory = true;             
         atApp.gotoPage(page);
     });
```

Button Page 2:

```
<div id="btnClose" class="btn-left btn-cancel">
        <span>Back</span>
    </div>
```

[image: app flow]

Comment: Yes it is. Is a framework for cordova/phonegap and is for the delay when touch a button, is not a yiiframework and not ui. https://cordova.codeplex.com/

Comment: it would be good if you explained more. By all appearances this is a UI issue. The code posted, the diagram posted, all indicate my response is mostly correct.  My previous answer stands with the correction: Please google [nova framework forum](https://www.google.com/search?q=nova+framework+forum). NOTE: your link points to a dead forum. Best of Luck.

Comment: Thanks for caring. I solved using the library called Fastclick.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem installing [FastClick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) and follow the ansewer of this question [how to use fastclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849637/how-to-use-fastclick-js-with-phonegap-and-jqm).